# SwiftUi: @Binding vs @ObservedObject usage

Tags: swiftui

I'm a bit lost trying to find out the use case for **@Binding** and **@ObservedObject** property wrappers in SwiftUI application. Here is a short example :

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = DataModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ClickView(
            numOfClicks: $model.clicks,
            model: model
        )
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
        .frame(width: 320, height: 240)
}
```

`ClickView` is implemented as follows :

```
import SwiftUI

struct ClickView: View {
    @Binding var numOfClicks: Int
    @ObservedObject var model: DataModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("Clicks : \(numOfClicks)")
            Button(action: {
                model.clicks += 1
            }, label: {
                Text("Tap me")
            }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

And here is `DataModel` class to make the picture full :

```
import Foundation

class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var clicks = 0
}
```

As you might see I use both @Binding and @ObservedObject to make a ref for the same object. Both approaches work fine. But what way should I follow and why? What is the difference/(pros and cons) here?

Answer (score 4):

- `@Binding` is for value types
- `@ObservedObject` is for reference types.

As you have a reference to `DataModel` anyway, I recommend to delete `numOfClicks` and *bind* to `model.clicks` directly. But in your code there is actually no `@Binding` (bidirectional connection with `$`) involved.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = DataModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ClickView(model: model)
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ClickView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: DataModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("Clicks : \(model.clicks)")
            Button(action: {
                model.clicks += 1
            }, label: {
                Text("Tap me")
            }
            )
        }
    }
}
```